# How to dynamically choose which table (with same schema) to select from in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I have a bit of an odd database model for a project - I'm going to have several tables with the same definition.  Each table stores information for different clients and because of security restrictions, we cannot put the data together in one table.  So it would look something like this...

```
table ClientOneData
(
    Id (PK, int, not null),
    Col1 (varchar(50), not null),
    etc.
)

table ClientTwoData
(
    Id (PK, int, not null),
    Col1 (varchar(50), not null),
    etc.
)
```

I want a single stored procedure to retrieve data from the appropriate table. I could do that by just passing the table name as a param to the proc and then building up a string of sql to execute...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetData
    @TableName varchar(100)

AS
BEGIN

    DECLARE @sql varchar(max)
    SET @sql = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @sql

    exec(@sql)
```

... but that seems fundamentally wrong to me.  And replicating code, either in the form of a giant case statement or by "one-offing" the proc and creating a new one for each client, also seems wrong.

Is there a better way to do this?

I'm pretty open to suggestions, anything from something I can do in the proc to re-working the data model (short of dumping all the data into a single table).  Upgrading to SQL-Server 2008 or 2010 *might* be an option, but would be a last resort.

Comment: Not sure what a stored procedure adds here.  I'd let the client decide which table to select.

Comment: What kind of data is in the table(s)?

Comment: @Jeremy Wiggins, can you expand on the security restrictions that prevent you from putting all customers in a single table?

Comment: @Mark Bannister - It's just a requirement, as in we said to the person we're building it for "we could put the data in a single table and relate it to different companies by a key" and they said "no, the data *must* be stored in separate tables".  It is what it is at this point.  At least we were able to talk them out of using a separate database for each company.  But they were big on keeping data separate for companies.

Comment: @Jeremy Wiggins, in that case the consolidated view looks like the best option - but it does underscore the pointlessness of the requirement for separate tables.

Comment: @Mark Bannister - It may be.  I'll need to check on what volume of data we expect to get in these.  I'm assuming it's safe to say that if we get enough of these tables and they each have a million or so records, performance is going to crash and burn pretty hard when querying that view.

Comment: It sounds like they are giving your requirements based on the expectation of poorly written and insecure code.  It's a shame when companies force developers to do this because they don't understand technology....

Comment: @Jeremy Wiggins - Not necessarily w/r/t crashing and burning.  If you have proper indexes and are using the correct criteria in your select you shouldn't have major issues.  In my environment we have a customer that we get 30-40million records a month, each month in it's own database, and we have views looking at 30-40 months (i.e. 40 dbs with a total of 1.6 billion records) and it runs fine.

Comment: Part of a developer's job is talking the business people out of trying to do technology work. That being said, without knowing a lot more about the system it's hard to make a recommendation. Having separate DBs might be best. Calling separate SPs might make sense. There are too many "it depends" things here.

Comment: @Tom H. - I agree 100%.  I talked to another developer and we're going to do a quick performance test on a very large table and then try to twist the client's arm into letting us do it the right way.  I think it's a possibility still.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a reasonably small number of tables you could combine them into a view and query that.  Example:

```
create view vw_MyTables
AS
   SELECT 'table1' as tableName, * from table1
   UNION
   SELECT 'table2', * from table2 
   UNION
   SELECT 'table3', * from table3 


SELECT * FROM vw_MyTables
WHERE tableName = @TableName
```

Otherwise I think your only option is dynamic sql...

If you are willing to change your schema around that would probably be best.  Is there a reason you store identical(is it identical?) information for clients in different tables?

I have used the following structure to represent this type of data before:

```
Client
--------
ClientId - pk
ClientName


ClientData
-----------
DataId - pk
ClientId - fk to Client
Whatever
```

This is basically what my view does but if you do it this way you can create indexes on it and get your datas wicked fast.

Answer (score 1):

If you absolutely *have* to separate the clients' data into separate tables, then I think the dynamic SQL is the best route. An alternative would be to have a view that selects from all client tables, like so:

```
create view AllClients as
select 'ClientOne' ClientName, c1.* from ClientOneData c1 union all
select 'ClientTwo' ClientName, c2.* from ClientTwoData c2 union all
.
.
.
etc.
```

- but this just replicates the single table that you have ruled out for security reasons, in a virtual form.

Answer (score 1):

I'd combine the data into a single table and implement [row-level security](http://www.drdobbs.com/database/215900773) instead of separating into separate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic SQL using a parameter verbatim is a security hole. Someone could exploit your sproc and pass a drop command, for instance.

Also a sproc with Dynamic SQL will recompile each time it is executed.

A sproc using Abe Miessler's view would be the proper way to do it: secured and not recompiled.

Comment: All of that may very well be, but that is not an answer to the question that was posed.